# Error while trying to merge parse and paypal projects

Tags: ios, swift, paypal, parse-platform

I was trying to merge a parse project with a paypal project but i'm stuck with this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'PayPalIncompleteIntegration', 
reason: 'preconnectWithEnvironment was called without a preceding call to initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments
```

This is the only code that i found relative with this error (MainViewController.swift):

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, PayPalPaymentDelegate,
PayPalFuturePaymentDelegate, PayPalProfileSharingDelegate,
FlipsideViewControllerDelegate {
var environment:String = PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork {
willSet(newEnvironment) {
  if (newEnvironment != environment) {
    PayPalMobile.preconnectWithEnvironment(newEnvironment)
  }
 }
}

.
. etc..
.


override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated)
PayPalMobile.preconnectWithEnvironment(environment)
}
```

This is from PayPalMobile.h:

```
/// You MUST preconnect to PayPal to prepare the device for processing payments.
/// This improves the user experience because it allows the PayPal Mobile SDK to make its
/// setup request early and in the background.
///
/// The preconnect is valid for a limited time, so the recommended time to preconnect
/// is when you present the UI in which users *might* choose to initiate payment.
///
/// Calling this method a second time, with a different value, will change the environment used
/// by subsequently allocated PayPal Mobile SDK viewcontrollers. Existing viewcontrollers
/// will be unaffected.
///
/// @param environment
/// The PayPal Mobile SDK can operate in different environments to facilitate development and testing.
/// See PayPalEnvironmentProduction, PayPalEnvironmentSandbox,
PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork for more details.
+ (void)preconnectWithEnvironment:(NSString *)environment;
```

(I've merged both storyboard too)

Could someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Please *[edit] the question* to add meaningful code. Posting a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers (see also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/)

Comment: Edited! I don't know anything else about this error. @Makyen

Answer (score 1):

Dave from PayPal here.

@IceHell, the sample code you're looking for is [here in ZZAppDelegate.m](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/SampleApp-Swift/PayPal-iOS-SDK-Sample-App/ZZAppDelegate.m#L14-20):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

#warning "Enter your credentials"
  [PayPalMobile initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:@{PayPalEnvironmentProduction : @"YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FOR_PRODUCTION",
                                                         PayPalEnvironmentSandbox : @"YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FOR_SANDBOX"}];
  return YES;
}
```

In addition to working from our sample code, before using the PayPal iOS SDK you'll also want to carefully review our detailed [integration instructions](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK#paypal-ios-sdk).

Comment: Hello Dave, first of all thanks for reply! I've already edited this code with my own credential but the error doesn't seems to be here. I've already followed the basic instructions and i created "my app" from the paypal dev site for a sandbox use. The problem is that when i tried the paypal app in solo all worked fine, now that i merged with parse code i get stuck within this error. Probably i missed some initiation for paypal into the parse code, but i don't get it. My app works like:a user login into my parse db, i'll show him some data into a table view and then he should be able to buy it.

Comment: @IceHell maybe try adding some breakpoints to confirm that the `initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:` call is actually being made prior to the `preconnectWithEnvironment:` call?

Comment: Ok probably i know what's wrong: when i merged both project, i didn't merged their AppDelegate, so my ZZAppDelegate.m is not called at all (i think). The problem is that i don't know how to do because one of them is in swift and the other one is in Obj-C. I'm pretty new to swift programming.